# Syntax error in jsTree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I've been playing around with the database demo from the jsTree website (https://www.jstree.com/demo_sitebrowser/index.php). I downloaded it on my server and just changed $.jstree.defaults.core.data.url and removed some listeners. The code is now this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
        <style>
        html, body { background:#ebebeb; font-size:10px; font-family:Verdana; margin:0; padding:0; }
        #container { min-width:320px; margin:0px auto 0 auto; background:white; border-radius:0px; padding:0px; overflow:hidden; }
        #tree { float:left; min-width:319px; border-right:1px solid silver; overflow:auto; padding:0px 0; }
        #data { margin-left:320px; }
        #data textarea { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%; border:0; background:white; display:block; line-height:18px; }
        #data, #code { font: normal normal normal 12px/18px 'Consolas', monospace !important; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" role="main">
            <div id="tree"></div>
            <div id="data">
                <div class="content code" style="display:none;"><textarea id="code" readonly="readonly"></textarea></div>
                <div class="content folder" style="display:none;"></div>
                <div class="content image" style="display:none; position:relative;"><img src="" alt="" style="display:block; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; padding:0; max-height:90%; max-width:90%;" /></div>
                <div class="content default" style="text-align:center;">Select a node from the tree.</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="//static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="//static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function () {
            $(window).resize(function () {
                var h = Math.max($(window).height() - 0, 420);
                $('#container, #data, #tree, #data .content').height(h).filter('.default').css('lineHeight', h + 'px');
            }).resize();

            $('#tree')
                .jstree({
                    'core' : {
                        'data' : {
                            'url' : './JSON/GetChildren',
                            'data' : function (node) {
                                return { 'id' : node.id };
                            }
                        },
                        'force_text' : true,
                        'check_callback' : true,
                        'themes' : {
                            'responsive' : false
                        }
                    }
                })
                .on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                    if(data && data.selected && data.selected.length) {
                        $.get('?operation=get_content&id=' + data.selected.join(':'), function (d) {
                            $('#data .default').text(d.content).show();
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#data .content').hide();
                        $('#data .default').text('Select a file from the tree.').show();
                    }
                });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

On loading, jsTree is requesting `./JSON/GetChildren?id=#` for rendering the first level nodes, which return this:
I've been playing around with the database demo from the jsTree website (https://www.jstree.com/demo_sitebrowser/index.php). I downloaded it on my server and just changed $.jstree.defaults.core.data.url and removed some listeners. The code is now this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
        <style>
        html, body { background:#ebebeb; font-size:10px; font-family:Verdana; margin:0; padding:0; }
        #container { min-width:320px; margin:0px auto 0 auto; background:white; border-radius:0px; padding:0px; overflow:hidden; }
        #tree { float:left; min-width:319px; border-right:1px solid silver; overflow:auto; padding:0px 0; }
        #data { margin-left:320px; }
        #data textarea { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%; border:0; background:white; display:block; line-height:18px; }
        #data, #code { font: normal normal normal 12px/18px 'Consolas', monospace !important; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" role="main">
            <div id="tree"></div>
            <div id="data">
                <div class="content code" style="display:none;"><textarea id="code" readonly="readonly"></textarea></div>
                <div class="content folder" style="display:none;"></div>
                <div class="content image" style="display:none; position:relative;"><img src="" alt="" style="display:block; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; padding:0; max-height:90%; max-width:90%;" /></div>
                <div class="content default" style="text-align:center;">Select a node from the tree.</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="//static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="//static.jstree.com/latest/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function () {
            $(window).resize(function () {
                var h = Math.max($(window).height() - 0, 420);
                $('#container, #data, #tree, #data .content').height(h).filter('.default').css('lineHeight', h + 'px');
            }).resize();

            $('#tree')
                .jstree({
                    'core' : {
                        'data' : {
                            'url' : './JSON/GetChildren',
                            'data' : function (node) {
                                return { 'id' : node.id };
                            }
                        },
                        'force_text' : true,
                        'check_callback' : true,
                        'themes' : {
                            'responsive' : false
                        }
                    }
                })
                .on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                    if(data && data.selected && data.selected.length) {
                        $.get('?operation=get_content&id=' + data.selected.join(':'), function (d) {
                            $('#data .default').text(d.content).show();
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#data .content').hide();
                        $('#data .default').text('Select a file from the tree.').show();
                    }
                });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

On loading, jsTree is requesting `./JSON/GetChildren?id=#` for rendering the first level nodes, which return this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 389,
    "text": "consequat",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 316,
    "text": "orci luctus",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 356,
    "text": "tellus non",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 328,
    "text": "dictum",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 335,
    "text": "auctor ullamcorper",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 355,
    "text": "id mollis",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 351,
    "text": "Morbi sit",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 358,
    "text": "sit",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 391,
    "text": "odio Phasellus",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 327,
    "text": "nunc",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 346,
    "text": "eu",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 386,
    "text": "lorem",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 333,
    "text": "metus vitae velit",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 367,
    "text": "orci Ut",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 336,
    "text": "auctor",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 322,
    "text": "quis diam Pellentesque",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 303,
    "text": "dolor",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 302,
    "text": "Aliquam auctor velit",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 304,
    "text": "turpis nec",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 349,
    "text": "Aliquam",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 382,
    "text": "Duis a",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 339,
    "text": "euismod mauris",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 310,
    "text": "facilisis facilisis magna",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 385,
    "text": "cursus",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 345,
    "text": "auctor",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 369,
    "text": "non hendrerit id",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 330,
    "text": "Curabitur consequat lectus",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "text": "ornare",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 332,
    "text": "mauris Suspendisse aliquet",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 365,
    "text": "dolor Nulla semper",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 361,
    "text": "convallis convallis",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 344,
    "text": "enim",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 348,
    "text": "quam",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 375,
    "text": "nec",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 384,
    "text": "ornare",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 342,
    "text": "amet ultricies",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 363,
    "text": "sociis natoque penatibus",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 326,
    "text": "tincidunt neque",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 353,
    "text": "ipsum porta elit",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 395,
    "text": "pharetra Quisque ac",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 400,
    "text": "imperdiet nec",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 352,
    "text": "sed turpis",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 381,
    "text": "quis accumsan convallis",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 393,
    "text": "nisl",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 317,
    "text": "volutpat ornare",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 323,
    "text": "Sed",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 376,
    "text": "arcu",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 315,
    "text": "amet ante Vivamus",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 359,
    "text": "euismod ac fermentum",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 368,
    "text": "gravida non sollicitudin",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 305,
    "text": "Aliquam",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 360,
    "text": "Integer sem",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 340,
    "text": "velit eget",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 341,
    "text": "erat semper",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 354,
    "text": "lacinia orci consectetuer",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 390,
    "text": "ridiculus",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 357,
    "text": "lobortis quis",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 301,
    "text": "Nullam",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "text": "Etiam",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 324,
    "text": "ut nisi",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 347,
    "text": "dictum augue",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 396,
    "text": "Quisque ornare",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 325,
    "text": "nec mollis vitae",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 364,
    "text": "risus Nulla eget",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 337,
    "text": "eu ligula Aenean",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 379,
    "text": "dis parturient",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 343,
    "text": "faucibus orci",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 312,
    "text": "imperdiet nec",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 318,
    "text": "ipsum sodales",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 338,
    "text": "lorem vitae odio",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 397,
    "text": "nec mauris blandit",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 374,
    "text": "vitae erat Vivamus",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 398,
    "text": "elit Curabitur sed",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 308,
    "text": "rhoncus Nullam velit",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 388,
    "text": "Duis",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 370,
    "text": "lorem",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 311,
    "text": "id",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 314,
    "text": "sit amet",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 383,
    "text": "metus In nec",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 394,
    "text": "consectetuer ipsum nunc",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 307,
    "text": "dui Cum",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 380,
    "text": "arcu ac",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 329,
    "text": "molestie",
    "children": true
  },
  {
    "id": 362,
    "text": "posuere enim",
    "children": true
  }
]
```

I am, however, getting a "syntax error"message and I don't see where it is coming from. JSON is valid, jsTree loads and request it, so what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this. The problem was that `./JSON/GetChildren?id=#`'s header wasn't set to `application/json`.